# Allow user submitted data from a button to a worksheet to which they don't have edit permissions

Tags: google-sheets

I have one shared worksheet that has a button to submit data to a second worksheet. Users submitting data from the first worksheet do not have editing privileges on the second worksheet. I don't want to give users edit permissions on the second worksheet, but I do want to allow them to submit data using the button on the first worksheet. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: There are ways, but if you're creating logs maybe the best way is to create a Google Forms that submits to a Google Sheets

Comment: I've already made a spreadsheet with all the calculations and buttons. I rather not have to start over to get this completed.... if anyone has any ideas that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Use an [installable "on edit" trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) to run the function that appends data to the target spreadsheet. The function will run under the account of the user who created the trigger, so the user at the keyboard does not need any access to the target spreadsheet.

One easy way is to use a checkbox instead of a button to start the script. The trigger function must check that the event involved that checkbox. See the [checkboxButtons_](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/119054769?msgid=120084104) script for sample code. That sample script uses a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers), but it is easy to use an installable trigger instead.

Answer (score 0):

There are several posts about this. With a button you won't be able to do it with a button. What I recommend specifically in your case is to run the script when there's an edit bye the user in a certain cell. For example a Tickbox, or a Drop-down menu (in a cell) that allows the user to select which function to run:

If you already have an onEdit function working, that's a simple trigger run by whoever is editing the sheet

In order to work this out, I encourage you to change your name function or extract in a new function the part about this specific code you're talking about; and set an installable trigger that runs on event. This way it'll be run as you used to but as it came from your own account. As you have permissions for editing that second sheet the process will be set by the installable trigger but the other user won't be able to edit it since he/she doesn't have the permissions. Try it and let me know!

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: I will take a look at it later today and see what i can do. Thank you for the information.